# whats the difference between cloning and extending backbone events object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

after a tutorial I've followed recently,  I've been using the following for custom events in my very small backbone app..

```
window.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

which is mirrored in backbone documentation, http://backbonejs.org/#Events

the documentation then goes on to state,

> For example, to make a handy event dispatcher that can coordinate
>   events among different areas of your application: var dispatcher =
>   _.clone(Backbone.Events)

this is maybe a newb question but what exactly is an event dispatcher?, and how is extending or cloning the events object different ?

EDIT: I've read that cloning performs only a shallow copy passing the existing values by reference, but to be honest I'm not entirely clear what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well cloning (http://underscorejs.org/#clone) creates a shallow copy of the object, but extending (http://underscorejs.org/#extend) takes all properties from the second object, puts them in the first, and returns the first object.

In other words, when you clone you start with 1 object and finish with 2, when you extend you start and finish with 2 objects (but the extended objects will have all of the second object's properties in addition to the ones it had before extension).

An event dispatcher allows for a pub sub pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern): some bits of the application "announce" things, and other bits of the app can listen and respond to them.

Comment: okay cool so in terms of creating an 'event dispatcher' is there any practical difference between the two methods I've described above ? is there a reason one would want to use one method over the other in a specific instance ?

Comment: Typically you'd extend "classes", but clone instances.

Comment: Cool, that helps, but in the context of the question which should I be doing here and is there any practical difference in its application ?

Comment: In this case I'd venture they're equivalent. But you should still use `extend` because with events you'll be adding the event aggregator to an object (e.g. `_.extend(myObject, Backbone.Events)`. The code above uses an empty object as the base object getting extended (for demonstration purposes), but that isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: thanks for all the info, I think I'm going to have to spend more time with this, I understand the pub/sub side of this in its application, but I think there are some nuances that aren't clear and I'll need to form some more specific questions. cheers.

Comment: For what it's worth, the app I wrote to go with my book (https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) uses event aggregators to propagate information in a decoupled manner. It uses Marionette, but should give some insights nonetheless. You can find it at https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction

Comment: Thats awesome will check it out.  Been Fearful of diving into marionette until I'm clear on backbone Basics.

Comment: (I'm not objective, so keep that in mind.) Personally, I found it easier to get a good grasp on Marionette first because it hides some of Backbone's boilerplate/complexity. Then, understanding more advanced Backbone concepts came easily.